# Treeview display image of a custom treenode to picturebox

Tags: c#

I'm kinda new to this and after searching, and trying things i still couldn't achieve what i wanted, so here`s my question. In a windows form application i have a treeview in which i add custom treenodes (the custom node extends the treenode class and the additional variable is of type Image). So, everytime i select a node i want its image (after i have loaded the image to the node, of course) to be displayed in the picturebox. I have tried the afterselecet event handler and the mouse click event handler, but still the image was not displayed. This is the final piece of code after a lot of experimenting :

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) 
{ 
     pictureBox1.Image = ((MyNode)(treeView1.SelectedNode)).MyImage; 
}
```

I'm sure i am missing something here but don't know what exactly. Any help would be appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: I made a simple test project to try and reproduce your problem. I made a class called CustomNode that inherits TreeNode and inside it is an Image property which's value is set to an image. In the form's load event, I added a new CustomNode to a treeview. Then after adding the node to the tree, I set a picture box's image to the node's image using the same kind of conversion you did and it worked fine. Could you show how you're adding the MyNodes to the tree? Mine is just this simple: `treeView1.Nodes.Add(new CustomNode());`

Comment: Yes and thank you for your time, i honestly appreciate it. I just managed to solve it. I was using a "SelectedNode" to check if a node is selected and when i was adding an image to the node, the node was the wrong one, i accidentily created a temporary treenode and saved the image to this one. Actually the piece of code i wrote above works just fine.

((CustomNode)(treeView1.SelectedNode)).MyImage = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

Above is the correct line to add an image to a selected custom node. Thanks again for your time!!! I hope this post helps others too.